# How to show SPS-PhoneticDisplayName in user profile pages?

Tags: user-profile, user-profile-property

According to 
[Default user profile property mappings for Active Directory Domain Services](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh147510(v=office.15).aspx), **SPS-PhoneticDisplayName** is one of default field sync with AD. In our SP2013 on-premise farm, I can query this field with PowerShell. However I find no where in the interface (both Central admin and Users' mysite pages) show this value.

Can I list this value on mysite thru configuration?